# Sort Dictionary [Key: [Key: Value]] by value - Swift

Tags: swift, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictonary that looks like this:

```
var dict = [Int: [String: Any]]()

dict[1] = ["nausea": 23, "other": "hhh"]
dict[2] = ["nausea": 3, "other": "kkk"]
dict[3] = ["nausea": 33,  "other" : "yyy"]
```

I want to sort the dictionary by the value of the dictionary value for key "nausea" from least to greatest.

To look like this:

```
sortedDict = [2: ["nausea": 3, "other": "kkk"], 1: ["nausea": 23, "other": "hhh"], 3: ["nausea": 33,  "other" : "yyy"]]
```

I tried to play around with it using .sort():

```
let sortedDict = dict.sort( { ($0["nausea"] as! Int) > ($1["nausea"] as! Int) })
```

but, obviously It didn't work because "nausea" isn't the key for the dictonary

Can someone show me how they would do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: A dictionary is un unordered data structure. If you need ordering, you will have to use an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Dictionary` is unordered by design, as the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary) clearly states:

> Every dictionary is an **unordered** collection of key-value pairs.

You are probably looking for an ordered type like `Array`.

```
var arrayDict = [
    ["nausea": 23, "other": "hhh"],
    ["nausea": 3, "other": "kkk"],
    ["nausea": 33,  "other" : "yyy"]
]

let sorted = arrayDict.sorted { $0["nausea"] as! Int < $1["nausea"] as! Int }
print(sorted)
```

**Update**: Even better as @LeoDabus suggested in the comment you can use an array of custom objects:

```
struct MyObject {
    var nausea: Int
    var other: String
}
var array = [
    MyObject(nausea: 23, other: "hhh"),
    MyObject(nausea: 3, other: "kkk"),
    MyObject(nausea: 33, other: "yyy")
]

let sorted = array.sorted { $0.nausea < $1.nausea }
print(sorted)
```

Comment: This still an ugly approach. OP should use an array of custom objects.

Comment: @LeoDabus I updated my answer. You are totally right, it is far more elegant.

Comment: @leoDabus Yeah, this is true. Just implemented it into my app, and it also fixes the other problem of my second post yesterday. My apologies for that...